# MySQL InnoDB unlock a row

Tags: mysql, database, innodb

I get a lock timeout when updating a certain row in the database. Other rows update okay.

```
#1205 - Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
```

How can I unlock this particular row?

Here are the two related tables. I'm trying to update the email on user. I don't think tenant should be causing any problems though.

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`user` (
  `username` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `email` VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL ,
  `password` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `created` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `last_login` TIMESTAMP NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`username`) )

ENGINE = InnoDB;


CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`tenant` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `username` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `address` VARCHAR(90) NULL ,
  `company` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `phone` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL ,
  `fax` VARCHAR(25) NULL ,
  `notes` TEXT NULL ,
  `contacts` TEXT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ,
  INDEX `fk_tenant_user1` (`username` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_tenant_user1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`username` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`user` (`username` )
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I ended up just running `FLUSH TABLE  user` and it seems fine now.

Comment: lifesaver, thank you, i had same problem in production!

Comment: yes a truly lifesaver! I've been struggling for two days and this command saves my life. Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

Try running the following in an interactive mysql client:

```
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS\G
```

And look at the currently open transactions. See if one of them is causing the row to be locked.

Comment: I found an operation called flush in phpmyadmin. Rows not locked anymore.

Answer (score 0):

In my case MySql fixed itself after 6-7 hours. (When I wake up to solve this problem. It was gone)